# Is it possible to fit any regression line to a set of data points?

Tags: regression

If you have a set of data points `(x1,y1), (x2,y2),...,(xn,yn)`

And you know it fits a trend `y=f(x)` where `f(x)` is a known function,

Say for example: `f(x)=A*x*sin(B*x)`

Providing `f(x)` is known, is it possible to fit a regression line to this data and get values for A and B (and any other coefficients involved) for any `f(x)`?

If it is possible, could you give me some insight into how I would find the regression coefficients of the curve example given above?

Comment: Yes, though I wouldn't call that a *line*, since it's um... not a line ;-)

Comment: The optimal solution may not be unique, though

Comment: You could estimnate the coefficients via nonlinear least squares. The alterantive is maximum likelihood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some MATLAB code that implements the idea in Claude Leibovici's answer.

First we generate some data

```
a = 10;
b = 2.5;
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 200)';            % 100 points between 0 and 2pi
y = a * sin(b * x) + 10*randn(size(x)); % y = a sin(bx) + noise
```

which look like this

[image]

Now you define your objective function, which will be a function of `b` only (since we will choose `a` by least squares)

```
function [mse, a] = obFun(b, x, y)
  sinbx = sin(b * x);
  a = sinbx \ y;          % choose a by OLS
  err = y - a * sinbx;    % compute error terms
  mse = mean(err.^2);
end
```

Say you suspect that the true value of `b` is in the interval [0, 5]. Then you can create some values in that interval, and compute the mean-square error on each value.

```
bValues = 0.01: 0.01: 5;
for i = 1:length(bValues)
  mse(i) = obFun(bValues(i), x, y);
end
```

The mean-square error as a function of `b` looks like this

[image]

So you can see that there is an obvious minimum near to 2.5. You can find out exactly where it is, and from that find out the optimal values of `b` and `a`.

```
[mseMin, j] = min(mse);
bOptimal = bValues(j);
[~, aOptimal] = obFun(bOptimal, x, y);

fprintf('a = %.3f, b = %.3f\n', aOptimal, bOptimal);
```

which results in

```
a = 10.548, b = 2.540
```

which are reasonably close to the true values of `a = 10.0` and `b = 2.5`.

Comment: Thanks for having put this very good answer here. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Nonlinear least squares is probably the easiest solution provided that you have reasonable starting values for $A$ and $B$.

Suppose that you do not know any starting point. What you can do is to fix $B$ at a given value and just compute $A$ according to $$A=\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n x_i y_i \sin (B x_i)}{\sum _{i=1}^n (x_i \sin (B x_i))^2 }$$ since the model is linear with respect to $A$ if $B$ is fixed. For this value of $A$, compute the sum of squares of errors and repeat for other values of $B$. Plot the sum of squares of errors as a function of $B$ until you have something close to a minimum. Now, you have your starting values.

If you want, post a dozen of data points and I shall show you how this works.

If the model had been $$y=A x \sin (B x)+C x^2+D x^3$$ the procedure I suggested could apply since, for a given value of $B$, parameters $A,C,D$ can be immediately obtained using multilinear regression. Then, a look at the plot of the sum of squares of errors as a function of $B$ tells you how to initialize the nonlinear square fit.